# Merge step of the Merge sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, pseudocode

I have a question and I hope someone could help me. I really don't understand the pseudo code of the merge step of the merge sort algorithm. I understand how it works but not the code. Would be grateful if someone could explain it to me:) thanks
[Merge sort pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjBem.png)
[Merge step pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPdqh.png)

I implemented the code but I did not understand it.

Comment: Add code using formatted text. To undertand how it works - just get pen, write two sorted lists and try to move elements to new list one-by-one using mergesort rules

Comment: yeah, but I don't understand what n1,n2 are for example and what this infinity means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n2` and `n2` are lengths of input subarrays - they are calculated using left-middle-right indices

Infinity value is used as sentinel to stop when you reach array end, also  to get rid off separate copying of array tails (when one array is exhausted)

Note this is mostly impractical, and in reality merge implementation often checks whether index of corresponding array is beyond the limits:

```
while i<=n1 and j<=n2:
   if L[i] <= R[j]: 
        A[k++] = L[i++]
   else:
        A[k++] = R[j++]
```

then move the rest:

```
while i<=n1:
    A[k++] = L[i++]
while j<=n2:
    A[k++] = R[j++]
```